# Extracting data from xml in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to query the SQL 2008R2 database `Surveillance` and extract the `MacAddress` value from this XML Column `Settings` in the table `Hardware` I'm brand new to SQL queries but quickly learning. Any suggestions would be GREATLY appreciated.

```
<properties>
  <settings hwid="hardware">
    <setting typeid="DAF813F8-2E02-4AE5-9F0F-B0FB203D3CB6">
      <name>ProductID</name>
      <value>AxisP3301</value>
    </setting>
    <setting typeid="F9D27CE8-8FA9-4B91-8C85-3E80DE7EF0AB">
      <name>MacAddress</name>
      <value>00408CC3ABCF</value>
    </setting>
    <setting typeid="FC714851-E998-4738-A140-F4FF20E99DEB">
      <name>FirmwareVersion</name>
      <value>5.40.9.2</value>
    </setting>
    <setting typeid="F1DED00E-9614-475F-A6F7-BA29FCA8DE39">
      <name>SerialNumber</name>
      <value>00408CC3ABCF</value>
    </setting>
    <setting typeid="5BE128A3-BDEC-4FEE-8690-D575DF03E3EE">
      <name>Bandwidth</name>
      <value>Unlimited</value>
    </setting>
    <setting typeid="188A93DE-67D8-417E-BCFC-FF5B3F74434A">
      <name>AudioEncoding</name>
      <value>G711</value>
    </setting>
    <setting typeid="5ADCDA37-78B3-4AB9-93E5-966EDE722FA3">
      <name>AlertEventServerIP</name>
      <value />
    </setting>
    <setting typeid="922AAF32-821A-4E24-A646-72A4AE592364">
      <name>AlertEventServerPort</name>
      <value>0</value>
    </setting>
    <setting typeid="18BF9B14-D675-40A1-B57D-90A03272468A">
      <name>SmtpEventServerIP</name>
      <value />
    </setting>
    <setting typeid="5F614912-4C46-453E-9043-3BFC15321E56">
      <name>SmtpEventServerPort</name>
      <value>25</value>
    </setting>
    <setting typeid="9F739984-A2C0-4E09-AAB6-97F229E9F208">
      <name>InternalEventServerIP</name>
      <value>25</value>
    </setting>
    <setting typeid="59094737-81C6-4FC2-B748-0005C390A775">
      <name>AttachmentSavePath</name>
      <value />
    </setting>
    <setting typeid="AF8875BC-7B45-4EBC-92DC-4E3959810A2E">
      <name>InternalEventServerPort</name>
      <value />
    </setting>
    <setting typeid="2B22F067-7AA4-4486-A206-85CBE3BE3285">
      <name>HTTPSPort</name>
      <value>443</value>
    </setting>
    <setting typeid="DA6E7891-54FA-4902-8164-75A790C11F17">
      <name>HTTPSEnabled</name>
      <value>no</value>
    </setting>
  </settings>
</properties>
```

Comment: Are you only looking at one row of data or are there multiple row with an XML data type you're trying to parse?

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 4):

You can use function [`value()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) and correct XQuery to get the result you need:

```
SELECT Settings.value('(/properties/settings/setting[name="MacAddress"]/value/text())[1]', 'varchar(255)') as MacAddress 
FROM Hardware
```

Here you find the `setting` element that has child element `name` with value `MacAddress` and take the text of its child element `value`. When using `value()` function you need to provide the data type, so it is provided as `varchar(255)` in this case.

Here is a link to [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f00ab/11)